# IOS Video Player

Tags: ios, cordova, vimeo

I was able to get my vimeo video's embeded into my app and play in the native video play when clicked. My question is, when using the native video player, is that actually webview or something completely separate. I'm trying to get the player to auto rotate since my app is all portrait mode. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this? I'm using phonegap to put together this app. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy in a standard Xcode Mac OS app should be this:

Window:
    View:
        QTMovieView

If you've got Xcode installed, you might want to check out this file on your hard disk:
file:///Library/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index.html#samplecode/MyMediaPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009203-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Not sure how you'd do it with PhoneGap, but here is how you'd do it in ObjectiveC

To get it to autorotate, all you have to do is have the view respond to the change in rotation.

The thing that controls the view (the view controller) is where this is done.

You'll need this in your interface of your view file:
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;

And this method later on in the .m file

(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

If you have the latest iOS SDK installed on your HD, you can also take a look at this project for iOS (AVPlayerDemo) that might help: file:///Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_0.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index.html#samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Comment: Hmmm, this is a little over my head but I'm trying to follow it. I can locate the appdelegate.m file but don't know what you mean by the "view file" could you clarify?

Comment: The line above the one where you have a problem with "view file", where is says "view controller".  Don't you have a view controller file that ends in .m?

Comment: I have a "AppDelegate.m" and a "AppDelegate.h". So do both lines of code go in the .m file? Sorry again for the noobie questions!

Comment: Hey Alex, any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Let me know, thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm in the middle of my own UITabBar fun. Check out Phonegap's docs on auto rotation.